# SocketRocket and pinning certificate error?

Tags: objective-c, socketrocket

I'm working with SocketRocket, so far everything has been working fine and today I wanted to try to pin down a (self signed) certificate but I get an error:

```
- (void)connectWebSocket {
    webSocket.delegate = nil;
    webSocket = nil;

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"wss://%@:%@", server_ip, server_port];

    //NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                             cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:5.0];


    // pin down certificate
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myOwnCertificate" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
    CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);
    id certificate = (__bridge id)certRef;
    [request setSR_SSLPinnedCertificates:@[certificate]];

    SRWebSocket *newWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest: request];
    newWebSocket.delegate = self;

    [newWebSocket open];

    socketIsOpen = true;

}
```

Error: No visible @interface for 'NSURLRequest' declares the selector 'setSR_SSLPinnedCertificates:'

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need `#import "SRWebSocket.h"`.

`SR_SSLPinnedCertificates` is a property on the `NSURLRequest (CertificateAdditions)` category in https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h

Answer (score 0):

The `request` needs to be a `NSMutableURLRequest` type. When your `request` is a `NSURLRequest` type, the `SR_SSLPinnedCertificates` is **readonly**, so you can **NOT** set it.

```
#pragma mark - NSURLRequest (CertificateAdditions)

@interface NSURLRequest (CertificateAdditions)

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSArray *SR_SSLPinnedCertificates;

@end

#pragma mark - NSMutableURLRequest (CertificateAdditions)

@interface NSMutableURLRequest (CertificateAdditions)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *SR_SSLPinnedCertificates;

@end
```

Change your code to this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                             cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:5.0];
```

This should works :)